# Pressing button on android phone with python

Tags: java, android, python

This is my first question here.

I am trying to write a python script which is from my PC , it should somehow press a button or make a call or swipe on an android phone device "version 4.4 for EX"  which is connected to my PC via USB cable connection.

This is in my point of view should be in a client-server approach.
Do you know from where shall I begin as I googled and I reached nothing.

python is just a choice not a must, so I may use JAVA app if it is easier.

What I need is, lets say :

```
AndroidDevice.press(3.122 , 4.44 );// which is pressing on coordinates for Ex
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Appium` for this.
`Appium` already provides all the api's you want.
With appium, you can use real device as well as android emulators with with different OS Versions.You can go through configurations and set up.You run Appium server locally and then using Java or Python you can send the commands.Appium provides its own api's which are wrappers over google's UI Automation.
Some python code snippet.

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.tap(x=xx, y=yy, count=cnt).release().perform()
```

You provide `x`,`y` and `count`.

Comment: Thanks.i heard about this one, but it is acting as webdriver as i understand. is there no python library which can directly control android device ?

Comment: @MohamedoufaAA you have python library which interacts with appium server.I dont think there is a direct way or my knowledge is limited at this point.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help

Comment: ok, i tried that.but seems there is a problem,is appium only for creating unit tests or test automation, i mean test scripts writing ? my use case is that i just need to press buttons or swipe screen in a script

Comment: @MohamedoufaAA appium does your use case with ease..... You can use it for your purpose....not necessarily for automation or testing....